# How to Overlay selected custom marker in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use `react-native-maps` to display an array of positions using custom marker. I want to overlay the selected maker, but did not found the right solution. Using `position: 'absolute'` for the selected marker changes its position in the map.

Here is the code of the `MapView`:

```js
<MapView
        style={styles.map}
        region={region} // initial region is user location if myPosition or coordinates of search
        // onRegionChange={onRegionChange}
      >
        <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <Marker
              onPress={() => handleMarkerPress(item)}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: item.latitude,
                longitude: item.longitude,
              }}
              // image={require('Resources/geoloc.png')}
              // pinColor={item.id === visibleItemId ? 'red' : 'blue'}
              key={item.id}>
              <MosqueMarquer
                mosqueImage={item.images}
                itemId={item.id}
                visibleItemId={visibleItemId}
                distance={item.distance_result}
              />
            </Marker>
          ))}
          {isUserGeoLoc ? (
            <Marker
              coordinate={{
                latitude: userLocation.latitude,
                longitude: userLocation.longitude,
              }}
              description={'Your are here'}>
              <Image
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={require('Resources/user_location.png')}
                style={{tintColor: '#4280ee', height: 25}}
              />
            </Marker>
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </MapView>
```

And here is the custom marker code:

```js
const MosqueMarquer = (props) => {

  const relativeStyle =
    props.itemId == props.visibleItemId
      ? {position: 'absolute', tintColor: '#428947', color: '#fff', zIndex: 1}
      : {position: null, tintColor: '#fff', color: '#3c423d', zIndex: 0};
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      resizeMode="contain"
      source={require('Resources/square_marker.png')}
      style={{
        ...styles.imageBackground,
         position: relativeStyle.position,
        zIndex: relativeStyle.zIndex,
      }}
      imageStyle={{tintColor: relativeStyle.tintColor}}>
      <Text style={{...styles.text, color: relativeStyle.color}}>
        {props.distance}m
      </Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default MosqueMarquer;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageBackground: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: common.FONT_SIZE_H38,
  },
});
```

the selected marker in green is under the none selected one:

[image]

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

```
  <XMarksTheSpot coordinates={coordinatesOfYOurMarker} center={center} />
```

XMarksTheSpot ->

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Polygon, Polyline, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

class XMarksTheSpot extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Polygon
          coordinates={this.props.coordinates}
          strokeColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
          strokeWidth={3}
        />
        <Polyline
          coordinates={[this.props.coordinates[0], this.props.coordinates[2]]}
        />
        <Polyline
          coordinates={[this.props.coordinates[1], this.props.coordinates[3]]}
        />
        <Marker coordinate={this.props.center} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

XMarksTheSpot.propTypes = {
  coordinates: PropTypes.array,
  center: PropTypes.object,
  zIndex: PropTypes.number,
};

export default XMarksTheSpot;
```